# Можно ли заполнять listview сразу из двух источников?

Tags: android, sqlite

Предположим, имеется ListView с кастомным ListItem, где есть три TextView. Можно ли сделать так, что два из них заполняются из БД, а третий программно с помощью, к примеру, цикла for?

Comment: Если у вас кастомный адаптер, то вы можете откуда угодно данные брать. )

Comment: Отлично, а если не кастомный? И что насчет того, чтоб третий textView заполнялся из переменной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listView это просто оболочка, а заполняет его (Array / Cursor) Adapter, и ему не известно, откуда берутся данные, незачем. Элементы списка принимают значения, затем методом `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` адаптер выводит их в ListView. Создайте AsyncTaks, в котором передаете данные для TextView, и в методе onPostExecute() обновите адаптер, вызвав `notifyDataSetChanged();`.